# Flutter question: How to hide the status bar while avoiding letterboxing (notch)

Tags: android, flutter, fullscreen

I am using `SystemChrome.setEnabledSystemUIOverlays([]);` to hide the status and navigation bars.

However, when I do that, the scaffold won't go past the notch area; which results in letterboxing.

When I don't hide them the scaffold goes past the notch as expected.

How do I make it so the scaffold takes all the screen real estate when I hide the bars?

Answer (score 0):

Just use **SafeArea()** widget. It will work in your case.

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(body: 
        SafeArea(
            child:YourWidgetHere()
        )
    );
```

You're done.